# How do I specify that a list property's contents are xml serialized, but the property itself should not be respresented in the markup?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I've got a class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("channel")]
public class Channel
{
   [XmlElement("title")]
   public String Title { get; set; }

   [WhatElseGoesHere]
   [XmlArrayItem("item")]
   public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

My desired output is this:

```
<channel>
   <title>The title</title>
   <item>{item content}</item>
   <item>{item content}</item>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) instead of [XmlArrayItemElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx):

```
[XmlRoot("channel")]
public class Channel
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was really stupidly simple... I never would've thought to try using XmlElementAttribute. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I actually tried Marc's answer first because I was "positive" this wouldn't work... and of course, it more or less generated your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could start with xml and work back? Put the desired xml in a file (`foo.xml`), then:

```
xsd foo.xml
xsd foo.xsd /classes
notepad foo.cs
```

This usually provides *an* answer - although you can usually do the same thing different ways.

Comment: Nice trick! It ended up generating darin's answer (more or less)